# Style attribute is not working in Play framework

Tags: html, css, scala, playframework

Creating a form in play-framework 2.3.x and want to show/hide it based on a model attribute. Generally If I hard code the style attribute like `style = "display: none"` and `style = "display: block"` it works, but when I want to change the style based on an attribute passed from the controller, style is not working at all.

Below is the code in, say, index.scala.html. getResultStyle method is used to generate the display style and using as value for style attribute in form tag.

```scala
@getResultStyle() = @{
  if(sf.year_1(1) == 0) {"display: none"} else {"display: block"}
} @main(message) {
     <form id="Forecast Result" name="Forecast Result"
        style=@getResultStyle()
        action="" method="post">
      .
      .
     </form>
```

Is there anyway I can make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to (add " " around definition):

```scala
 style="@getResultStyle()"
```

You code looks like (in html- check in browser)

```html
<form id="Forecast Result" name="Forecast Result"
        style=display:none
        action="" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check in browser.

Comment: it looks like style="display:" none in my browser